# How do I find the path to a program in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I installed an application and now I can access it via terminal as myapplication. It is an alias, though. How can I find the full path to the file?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use `type` and `which` to determine what a certain command in `bash` is, and, if it's an application, where it resides.

```
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
$ type -P ls
/Users/danielbeck/bin/ls
$ which which
/usr/bin/which
$ which ls
/Users/danielbeck/bin/ls
```

The commands `which` and `type -P` only work for programs on your `PATH`, of course, but you won't be able to run others by just typing their command name anyway.

---

If you're looking for a simple way to determine where an OS X (GUI) application bundle is installed (as used e.g. by the `open` command), you can execute the following short AppleScript from the command line:

```
$ osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to POSIX path of (file of process "Safari" as alias)'
/Applications/Safari.app
```

This requires that the program in question (Safari in the example) is running.

Comment: Is there a way to get the same result as your osascript but without the program running ?

Answer (score 8):

If the program is running, you can call

```
ps -ef | grep PROGRAM
```

Comment: or save a pipe and just use `pgrep -lf PROGRAM`

Answer (score 5):

On MAC (OS X) you can do:

1. Locate the application in Finder.
2. Right-click the application and
   select "Show Package Contents."
3. Locate the executable file: Typically, this is in Contents → MacOS, and has the same name as the application.
4. Drag that file onto your blank Terminal command line.

Now you can see the full path to your application on the command line and run it from there if you want.

Taken from [wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Open-Applications-Using-Terminal-on-Mac)

Answer (score 4):

This is the method I currently to locate the Firefox application directory in OSX and Linux.  Should be easy to adopt to another application.  Tested on OSX 10.7, Ubuntu 12.04, Debian Jessie

```
#!/bin/bash

# Array of possible Firefox application names.
appnames=("IceWeasel" "Firefox")    # "Firefox" "IceWeasel" "etc

#
# Calls lsregister -dump and parses the output for "/Firefox.app", etc.
# Returns the very first result found.
#
function get_osx_ffdir()
{
    # OSX Array of possible lsregister command locations
    # I'm only aware of this one currently
    lsregs=("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister")

    for i in "${lsregs[@]}"; do
        for j in ${appnames[@]}; do
            if [ -f $i ]; then
                # Some logic to parse the output from lsregister
                ffdir=$($i -dump |grep -E "/$j.app$" |cut -d'/' -f2- |head -1)
                ffdir="/$ffdir"
                return 0
            fi
        done
    done
    return 1
}

#
# Uses "which" and "readlink" to locate firefox on Linux, etc
#
function get_ffdir()
{
    for i in "${appnames[@]}"; do
        # Convert "Firefox" to "firefox", etc
        lower=$(echo "$i" |tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
        # Readlink uses the symlink to find the actual install location
        # will need to be removed for non-symlinked applications
        exec=$(readlink -f "$(which $lower)")
        # Assume the binary's parent folder is the actual application location
        ffdir=$(echo "$exec" |rev |cut -d'/' -f2- |rev)
        if [ -f "$ffdir" ]; then
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1

}


echo "Searching for Firefox..."

ffdir=""
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
    # Mac OSX
    get_osx_ffdir
else
    # Linux, etc
    get_ffdir
fi

echo "Found application here: $ffdir"

# TODO: Process failures, i.e. "$ffdir" == "" or "$?" != "0", etc
```

Comment: That's an impressive chuck of code.  Does it do anything that `type` and `type -P` don't?  Does the non-OSX code work on OS X?  If not, can you explain why not?  If yes, why do you have two versions?

Comment: @G-Man:  Due to character limitations, I'll answer this in two parts... 

On OSX, 3rd party applications aren't installed to `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, etc but instead installed to `/Applications/My3rdPartyApp.app` and the binary is stored in a subdirectory `Contents/MacOS` making it quite difficult to use any cross-platform techniques to determine the location of the application (hence the use of `lsregister`)  Worse yet, the OSX directory structure places the binary in a separate location from the resources.  The snippet above was written to assist with locating Firefox's `defaults/pref` dir.

Comment: On Ubuntu, `/usr/bin/firefox` isn't actually the Firefox binary, so I use the output of `readlink` to locate where it points to, and then find the `defaluts/prefs` directory from there.  On a side note, about the symlinking:  Doing `ls -al /usr/bin/* |grep -- '->' |wc -l` illustrates about 303 binaries in that directory my Ubuntu configuration are actually symlinks. (about 16% of them) For this reason, the above code **should * eventually be modified to resolve symlinks recursively until it finds the canonical path to the binary.

Comment: Last, to answer the `type -P` question, I'm not familiar enough with that command to answer the question.  Perhaps you can elaborate a bit. :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  (You might want to [edit] that information *into* your answer.)  I mention `type` because it was the basis of the first (& accepted) answer.  It is a shell builtin that indicates how specified name(s) would be interpreted if used as commands.  The POSIX version of it, which is rather bare-bones, is described [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  The `bash` version of `type` supports a handful of options; see [bash(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?bash) or the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-type).  The `-P` option forces a `PATH` search for each name, even if it is also an alias, function, builtin, or keyword; but, to answer my own question, it doesn’t do `readlink`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  If you feel the snippet has room for improvement, please do.  I've intentionally tried to make the comments explanatory without being TL;DR, but if there is anything non-obvious, please add it in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "**alias**" command in terminal to list all of your aliases. Or if you are in a directory you can use "**pwd**" to show your current path.

If you know the filename or a part of filename, then you can use "**find**" to locate your file.

```
find / -name things.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

The path of binaries is referenced in the `$PATH` variable.

You can see its content with `env`.

Comment: error in os... sorry :'(

Comment: Your answer isn't entirely clear, sorry. What do you mean with "error in os… sorry"? Also the `$PATH` can be viewed with `env`, but `echo $PATH` would be less verbose.